# A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, mshtml

> A script on this page is causing your web browser to run slowly

I am trying to get content of multiple web pages in a loop, after browsing ~ 38 URLs the code become irresponsible, below is the code. The intent of this activity. I have looked for multiple option on web nothing helped.

---

*This code section getting the page content of URL passed as parameter*

---

```
public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument GetPageSource(string url)
{
    webBrowserCtrl = new WebBrowser();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    StringReader content = null;
    webBrowserCtrl.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    webBrowserCtrl.Navigate(url);
    waitTillLoad(webBrowserCtrl);
    IHTMLDocument3 documentAsIHtmlDocument = null;

    try
    {
        documentAsIHtmlDocument = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)webBrowserCtrl.Document.DomDocument;
        content = new StringReader(documentAsIHtmlDocument.documentElement.outerHTML);
        doc.Load(content);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.Write("Exception from web Page: {0}", url);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (documentAsIHtmlDocument != null)
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(documentAsIHtmlDocument);
            documentAsIHtmlDocument = null;
        }
        content.Dispose();
        content.Close();
        webBrowserCtrl.Dispose();
        System.GC.Collect();
        System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        EmptyWorkingSet(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);
    }
    return doc;
}

private void waitTillLoad(WebBrowser webBrControl)
{
    while (webBrControl.IsBusy)
       Application.DoEvents();
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        if (webBrControl.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
        else
            break;
    }

    WebBrowserReadyState loadStatus;
    int waittime = 100000;
    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000);

    int counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
        Application.DoEvents();
        if ((counter > waittime) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Uninitialized) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Loading) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive))
        {
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
    counter = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && webBrControl.IsBusy != true)
        {
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you running this in a Winforms, WPF, web or console app?

Comment: Running this in a Console app

Comment: Is there a reason for using a WebBrowser?  HAP has HtmlWeb() as a way to load a URL.

Comment: This is a diagnostic that is generated by the browser itself and has nothing to do with C# or the framework.  It occurs when embedded JavaScript is burning too much core.  That *might* be helped along by your code loading pages too quickly.  Only thing you could do is sleep longer between page switches.  Or just not make it visible at all, this is surely but an assault on human eyes.

Comment: @GarRock, have you look at this [Error message: "A script on this page is causing Internet Explorer to run slowly"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/175500/error-message-a-script-on-this-page-is-causing-internet-explorer-to-ru)? If modding this value, make sure to make this change local to your process by using something like `RegOverridePredefKey`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your waitTillLoad function. You should not do ANY processing of the HTML document of any kind, until AFTER you leave the method where your tell your web browser to navigate. Its a threading thing since your web browser and your GUI are on the same thread you need to use the events to get stuff done.

So you should first hook into the `DocumentCompleted` Event, and then call your waitTillLoad  like so:

```
 public HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument GetPageSource(string url)
    {
        webBrowserCtrl = new WebBrowser();
        HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        StringReader content = null;
        webBrowserCtrl.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        webBrowserCtrl.Navigate(url);
        webBrowserCtrl.DocumentCompleted += webBrowserCtrl_DocumentCompleted;
    }


        private void webBrowserCtrl_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        waitTillLoad(webBrowserCtrl);
        IHTMLDocument3 documentAsIHtmlDocument = null;

        try
        {
            documentAsIHtmlDocument = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument3)webBrowserCtrl.Document.DomDocument;
            content = new StringReader(documentAsIHtmlDocument.documentElement.outerHTML);
            doc.Load(content);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.Write("Exception from web Page: {0}", url);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (documentAsIHtmlDocument != null)
            {
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(documentAsIHtmlDocument);
                documentAsIHtmlDocument = null;
            }
            content.Dispose();
            content.Close();
            webBrowserCtrl.Dispose();
            System.GC.Collect();
            System.GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            EmptyWorkingSet(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle);
        }
        return doc;
    }
    private void waitTillLoad(WebBrowser webBrControl)
    {
        while (webBrControl.IsBusy)
            Application.DoEvents();
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            if (webBrControl.ReadyState != System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(10);
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        WebBrowserReadyState loadStatus;
        int waittime = 100000;
        //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000000);

        int counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if ((counter > waittime) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Uninitialized) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Loading) || (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Interactive))
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }
        counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            loadStatus = webBrControl.ReadyState;
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (loadStatus == WebBrowserReadyState.Complete && webBrControl.IsBusy != true)
            {
                break;
            }
            counter++;
        }

    }
}
```